# Slide up transition with vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am new to vue, and just found out about vue transitions. I am trying to move a div up and expand its width on click of the div, but i haven't fully grasped the concept of the transition yet. Below is the image of what I am trying to achieve and the code.

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <transition name="slide">
      <div class="meal__status">
        <a @click="toggle = !toggle; move();" class="meal__status-wrap"></a>
      </div>
    </transition>
    <div v-if="toggle" class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      toggle: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    move() {}
  }
};
</script>
```

```
<style scoped>
.overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  opacity: 1;
}
.meal__status-wrap {
  background-color: #42b983;
  height: 60px;
  width: 70px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
}

</style>
```

this is the link to the code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-matsumoto-7rlxb?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

this is what I have[image]

this is what I am trying to achieve
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitions are only for when an element is shown/hidden with v-if or v-show. Because you aren't using `v-if` or `v-show` you shouldn't try and use a transition.

Instead, toggle a class on the element with an `@click` handler and then style the element based on that class.

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <div
      class="meal__status"
      :class="{ 'meal__status--active': mealStatusActive }"
      @click="mealStatusActive = !mealStatusActive"
    ></div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      mealStatusActive: false
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

```
<style scoped>
.meal__status {
  background-color: #42b983;
  height: 60px;
  width: 70px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
}
.meal__status--active {
  margin-top: -60px;
  width: 100%;
}
.overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
```

Comment: The width does not increase @BryceHowitson

Comment: @AdogaPatricia Not sure how I can help you with that. I'd have to see updated code at least.

Comment: @BryceHowitson it works, mistake in my class name, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Vue Transition is made to work between [Vue states or routes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html) (think page transition). I'm sure you could use it for an on-screen animation but that feels like plain old `@keyframe` animation in CSS would be just as easy for what you want.

Anyway, To get started with Vue Transitions, you need to wrap the element to be transitioned inside the transition tags. Then you need to give it a condition of some kind `v-if` is a simple example where if the condition is met the element will be rendered.

```
<transition name="myTransition">
  <div class="someClass" v-if="myCondition">Thingy to transition</div>
  <!-- you can have multiple elements in here -->
</transition>
<button v-on:click="myCondition = !myCondition">Toggle</button>
```

Then you need to define the CSS to go with a [bunch of states](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Classes) based on the transition name. Using Opacity as an example:

```
.someClass {
   transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
.someClass.myTransition-enter {
   /* example showing chained classes since the myTransition- is added */
   opacity: 0;
}
.someClass.myTransition-enter-to {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Vue automatically adds and removes those classes from the element with `v-if` at different stages.

Vue can transition an element's state as well but that's done without [Vue Transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitioning-state.html).

Answer (score 0):

I saw your duplicate thread, your issue in the sample code is about css. You should change the box width from `70px` to `100%` when you click on the box. To do that, create an other css class:

```
.meal__status--active .meal__status-wrap {
  background-color: #42b983;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```